# Python code isn't being executed after webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)

Tags: python, selenium, flask

I have a little flask application, which runs specific website on the server using chrome browser and make some tests once it gets request. Here is the part of code where specific url is being opened using chrome web browser.

```
def testrun(file, url, apiUrl):
    openFile(file)
    webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
    time.sleep(5)
    checkAppIsRunning("AmcEngine.exe")
    responseContent = requests.get(apiUrl)
    respjson = responseContent.json()
    slackResponse(checkAnswers (respjson, ID))
    os.system("taskkill /im chrome.exe")
```

The problem is that after `webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)` line the rest part of the code isn't being executed untill I close chrome manually.
What's interesting that when chrome is already opened when I am running this function, all code is being executed (opens new tab  on this line `webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)` ), but when chrome is closed (and new chrome instance is being opened by the function instead of opening the url in new tab) code is not working after the mentioned above line.

which way to dig?

Comment: sorry for bad description. I meant when chrome is closed and the function runs a new instance of chrome instead of opening new tab, the problem occurs

Comment: as an workaround threading can be used, so that `webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)` is in separate function which is being called via thread. However, this is not a solution I think.